# How do I solve this uncaught reference error: like_post is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick?

Tags: javascript

I recently live hosted my website and got this error.
**Uncaught ReferenceError: like_post is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick**

This error did not occur on the local server but it occurred on a public server. I saw a few threads regarding this error and I heard that you should use addEventListener instead of onclick in your code. However, I'm not sure how to implement it into my code so it would be great if you could help me.

This is the line where the error occurred:

```
<a onclick="like_post(event)" href="<?= ROOT ?>like/post/<?php echo $ROW['postid'] ?>" style="text-decoration:none;float:left;position:relative;top:2px;">
                <svg id="icon_like" fill="<?= $Like_color ?>" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M21.216 8h-2.216v-1.75l1-3.095v-3.155h-5.246c-2.158 6.369-4.252 9.992-6.754 10v-1h-8v13h8v-1h2l2.507 2h8.461l3.032-2.926v-10.261l-2.784-1.813zm.784 11.225l-1.839 1.775h-6.954l-2.507-2h-2.7v-7c3.781 0 6.727-5.674 8.189-10h1.811v.791l-1 3.095v4.114h3.623l1.377.897v8.328z" />
                </svg>
            </a>
```

This is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function() {
        function ajax_send(data, element) {

            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

            ajax.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {

                if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {

                    response(ajax.responseText, element);
                }

            });

            data = JSON.stringify(data);

            ajax.open("post", "<?= ROOT ?>ajax.php", true);
            ajax.send(data);

        }
     
        function response(result, element) {

            if (result != "") {

                var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                if (typeof obj.action != 'undefined') {

                    if (obj.action == 'like_post') {

                        var likes = "";

                        if (typeof obj.likes != 'undefined') {
                            likes =
                                (parseInt(obj.likes) > 0) ?
                                '<svg fill="#1877f2" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21.216 8h-2.216v-1.75l1-3.095v-3.155h-5.246c-2.158 6.369-4.252 9.992-6.754 10v-1h-8v13h8v-1h2l2.507 2h8.461l3.032-2.926v-10.261l-2.784-1.813zm.784 11.225l-1.839 1.775h-6.954l-2.507-2h-2.7v-7c3.781 0 6.727-5.674 8.189-10h1.811v.791l-1 3.095v4.114h3.623l1.377.897v8.328z"/></svg>' :
                                '<svg fill="#626a70cf" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21.216 8h-2.216v-1.75l1-3.095v-3.155h-5.246c-2.158 6.369-4.252 9.992-6.754 10v-1h-8v13h8v-1h2l2.507 2h8.461l3.032-2.926v-10.261l-2.784-1.813zm.784 11.225l-1.839 1.775h-6.954l-2.507-2h-2.7v-7c3.781 0 6.727-5.674 8.189-10h1.811v.791l-1 3.095v4.114h3.623l1.377.897v8.328z"/></svg>';
                            element.innerHTML = likes;
                        }

                        if (typeof obj.info != 'undefined') {
                            var info_element = document.getElementById(obj.id);
                            info_element.innerHTML = obj.info;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     
        function like_post(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var link = e.currentTarget.href;

            var data = {};
            data.link = link;
            data.action = "like_post";
            ajax_send(data, e.currentTarget);
        }
     }
     
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use window.onload?
Without it, it works : )

```js
function ajax_send(data, element) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            response(ajax.responseText, element);
        }
    });
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    ajax.open("post", "<?= ROOT ?>ajax.php", true);
    ajax.send(data);
}
function response(result, element) {
    if (result != "") {
        var obj = JSON.parse(result);
        if (typeof obj.action != 'undefined') {
            if (obj.action == 'like_post') {
                var likes = "";
                if (typeof obj.likes != 'undefined') {
                    likes = (parseInt(obj.likes) > 0) ? '<svg fill="#1877f2" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21.216 8h-2.216v-1.75l1-3.095v-3.155h-5.246c-2.158 6.369-4.252 9.992-6.754 10v-1h-8v13h8v-1h2l2.507 2h8.461l3.032-2.926v-10.261l-2.784-1.813zm.784 11.225l-1.839 1.775h-6.954l-2.507-2h-2.7v-7c3.781 0 6.727-5.674 8.189-10h1.811v.791l-1 3.095v4.114h3.623l1.377.897v8.328z"/></svg>' :
                        '<svg fill="#626a70cf" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21.216 8h-2.216v-1.75l1-3.095v-3.155h-5.246c-2.158 6.369-4.252 9.992-6.754 10v-1h-8v13h8v-1h2l2.507 2h8.461l3.032-2.926v-10.261l-2.784-1.813zm.784 11.225l-1.839 1.775h-6.954l-2.507-2h-2.7v-7c3.781 0 6.727-5.674 8.189-10h1.811v.791l-1 3.095v4.114h3.623l1.377.897v8.328z"/></svg>';
                    element.innerHTML = likes;
                }
                if (typeof obj.info != 'undefined') {
                    var info_element = document.getElementById(obj.id);
                    info_element.innerHTML = obj.info;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function like_post(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = e.currentTarget.href;
    var data = {};
    data.link = link;
    data.action = "like_post";
    ajax_send(data, e.currentTarget);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="like_post(event)" href="<?= ROOT ?>like/post/<?php echo $ROW['postid'] ?>" style="text-decoration:none;float:left;position:relative;top:2px;">
  <svg id="icon_like" fill="<?= $Like_color ?>" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M21.216 8h-2.216v-1.75l1-3.095v-3.155h-5.246c-2.158 6.369-4.252 9.992-6.754 10v-1h-8v13h8v-1h2l2.507 2h8.461l3.032-2.926v-10.261l-2.784-1.813zm.784 11.225l-1.839 1.775h-6.954l-2.507-2h-2.7v-7c3.781 0 6.727-5.674 8.189-10h1.811v.791l-1 3.095v4.114h3.623l1.377.897v8.328z" />
  </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: It only works on local server but not public server

Comment: @rustyrice23 Is there an error message about this on the public server?

Comment: No only an error in the console

Comment: @rustyrice23 That's what I meant, can you send the error?

Comment: The error's at the top of the thread: Uncaught ReferenceError: like_post is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: Ok that's weird .. local does it work and on the public server returns this error? Have you uploaded all the files that were changed?

Comment: Yes I've already updated my files

Comment: Okay .. then I don't know what you can do.